# Given n input strings and m query strings, find each query frequency in the list of input strings

Tags: java, programming-challenge

I'm doing questions on HackerRank to brush up on Java & CS.

---

**Problem**

This problem is called *Sparse Arrays* in HackerRank.

> There is a collection of input strings and a collection of query
>   strings. For each query string, determine how many times it occurs in
>   the list of input strings.
>
> For example, given input `strings = ['ab', 'ab', 'bc']` and `queries =
>   ['ab', 'abc', 'bc']`, result is `[2, 1, 0]`
>
> [Full Question](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sparse-arrays/problem)

**Solution**

```
static int[] matchingStrings(String[] strings, String[] queries) {
    Map<String, Integer> counter = new HashMap<>();
    for (String current: strings) {
        counter.put(current, counter.getOrDefault(current, 0) + 1);
    }

    int[] result = new int[queries.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < queries.length; i++) {
        result[i] = counter.getOrDefault(queries[i], 0);
    }
    return result;
}
```

This passes all the test cases.

1. Can I do it in a better way?
2. Can this be simplified in Java-8, 11 or later?

Comment: I checked the history of edits for your question and originally it didn't look very clear. Maybe that's why someone downvoted that version.

Comment: Fair enough.. Sparse Array title might've been confusing. Hopefully new title makes more sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I do it in a better way?

From the time complexity or space complexity your solution is good enough. Your store all your string frequencies beforehand so that to retrieve a frequency by any given string in `O(1)` time later. Also, it passes all the test cases so it's a good sign too.

Below are a couple of concerns regarding other aspects of your code.

**Variable Naming**

Your choice of variable names should be improved. For instance, `Map<String, Integer> counter` doesn't really reflect for what it stands for. I would call it `stringFrequencyMap` or `stringCountMap`.

Also, `result` sounds too generic here. How about `queryResults`?

I'll leave it up to you to think about other variable names you have (luckily not many left :) ).

**Static method**

I guess you've kept this method `static` as it was like this by default and to avoid creating an instance of your `Solution` class in the `main()` method. While it's fine for a small challenge like yours, generally there should be a good reason to add `static` to your method.

**Improvements**

> Can this be simplified in Java-8, 11 or later?

Of course, if we just use **JAVA 8** then we can take advantage of `streams` and write a solution as :

```
static long[] matchingStrings(String[] strings, String[] queries) {
    Map<String, Long> stringCountMap = Arrays.stream(strings).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), counting()));

    return Arrays.stream(queries).mapToLong(query -> stringCountMap.getOrDefault(query, 0L)).toArray();
}
```

As you can see, we do this in 2 steps. First, we calculate a frequency map and then calculate an array of results using streams again. Please note that I changed the return type from `int[]` to `long[]`.

**UPDATE**

Since there was a question why I've used `Map<String, Long>` rather than `Map<String, Integer>` - well, `Long` can hold bigger numbers. But since it's irrelevant for this problem here's a solution for `Map<String, Integer>`:

```
int[] matchingStrings(String[] strings, String[] queries) {
    Map<String, Integer> stringCountMap = Arrays.stream(strings).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), summingInt(x -> 1)));

    return Arrays.stream(queries).mapToInt(query -> stringCountMap.getOrDefault(query, 0)).toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have some suggestions for your code.

1) Since we know the size of the output, I suggest that you initialize the `java.util.HashMap` with the size + 1, since the default capacity of a `Map` is 16; this will prevent the map to do a rehashing if you have more than 16 values.

If you want more information about the rehashing / load factor, you can read the `java.util.HashMap` [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html).

```java
//[...]
int queryLength = queries.length;
Map<String, Integer> counter = new HashMap<>(queryLength + 1);
//[...]
```

2) I suggest that you create a method to create a `Map` containing the count of the similar string; instead of building it in the method.

```java
static int[] matchingStrings(String[] strings, String[] queries) {
    int queryLength = queries.length;
    Map<String, Integer> counter = getSimilarStringCountMap(strings, queryLength);
    //[...]
}


private static Map<String, Integer> getSimilarStringCountMap(String[] strings, int queryLength) {
    Map<String, Integer> counter = new HashMap<>(queryLength + 1);

    for (String current : strings) {
        counter.put(current, counter.getOrDefault(current, 0) + 1);
    }
    return counter;
}
```

**Refactored code**

````java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] strings = {"ab", "ab", "bc"};
        String[] queries = {"ab", "abc", "bc"};

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(matchingStrings(strings, queries)));
    }

    static int[] matchingStrings(String[] strings, String[] queries) {
        int queryLength = queries.length;

        Map<String, Integer> counter = getSimilarStringCountMap(strings, queryLength);

        int[] result = new int[queryLength];
        for (int i = 0; i < queryLength; i++) {
            result[i] = counter.getOrDefault(queries[i], 0);
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static Map<String, Integer> getSimilarStringCountMap(String[] strings, int queryLength) {
        Map<String, Integer> counter = new HashMap<>(queryLength + 1);

        for (String current : strings) {
            counter.put(current, counter.getOrDefault(current, 0) + 1);
        }

        return counter;
    }
```
````